# Mapping integer to alphabet and print all combination base on a 3 digit input

Tags: python

I was given this question by a co-worker:

Given that: '1' match to 'a', '2' to 'b' , '3' to 'c'...like wise... '26' to 'z'.

How can I get an output that follow this pattern :
if I get an input d="111", the output should be: aaa, ak, ka
/ (111)->aaa, (1, 11)->ak, (11,1)->ka

I create the following script, but I know that it is too long.

```
str1 = ""
str2=""
str3=""
d = "101"

for i in d:
    if "0" in i:
        pass
    else:
        str1 += chr(int(i)+96)

if int(d[0]) == 1:
    str2 += chr(int(d[0]+d[1])+96)
    str2 += chr(int(d[2])+ 96)
elif int(d[0]) == 2 and int(d[1]) < 7 :
    str2 += chr(int(d[0] + d[1]) + 96)
    str2 += chr(int(d[2]) + 96)
if int(d[1]) == 1:
    str3 += chr(int(d[0])+ 96)
    str3 += chr(int(d[1]+d[2])+96)
elif int(d[0]) == 2 and int(d[1]) < 7 :
    str3 += chr(int(d[1] + d[2]) + 96)
    str3 += chr(int(d[0]) + 96)


print str1
print str2
print str3
```

I would like to know a better way to tackle this.

Comment: create list `chars = [None, 'a', 'b', ...]` and then `char[int("1")]` gives you `a`, etc.

Comment: you can use slicing `"111"[:x]` and `"111"[x:]` to split on two parts. Use different `x` to get different parts `"111"[:0], "111"[0:] -> "", "111"`, `"111"[:1], "111"[1:] -> "11", "1"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on both K. Weston’s and bigballer’s answer, here is what I would do.

1. create a dict to map numbers to letters
2. recurse over the permutations of the input to get possible outputs

   ```
   letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   values = {
       i + 1: x for i, x in enumerate(letters)
   }

   def permutations(st):
       # we only need 1, 2 here because letter values are always less than one digit
       # don't worry about the '01' corner case since it wasn't defined in the problem, but easy to avoid with an extra if
       for x in range(1, 3):
           value = st[:x]
           # avoid yielding the same substring twice for 1-character st
           if len(val) < x: continue
           next_ = st[x:]
           value = int(value)
           # make sure our value maps to a letter
           # in 'a'..'z'
           value = values.get(value)
           if value is not None:
               if next_:
                   for y in permutations(next_):
                       yield value + y
               else:
                   yield value
   ```

And since this is a generator function, you can use it like this:

```
for x in permutations('111'):
    print x
```

Comment: I never work with yield before, so it is hard for me to understand how this script work. Do you think it is possible to chat about this script? Thanks

Comment: Sure.  Will try and catch you at some point over the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary:

A dictionary is just like an array, but it has key-value pairs.

For example:

```
alphabet = {1 : 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
print alphabet[1]
>a
```

In your case:

```
print alphabet[int(i)]
```

if i were 3 it would print 'c'.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

edit, i completed to code for you, the trick is that since the alphabet is small, we can brute force generate every combination of letters and store them in a lookup table:

```
from itertools import product
from string import lowercase
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for r in (2, 3):
    for p in product(lowercase,repeat=r):
         p = list(p)
         d[''.join(map(str,(ord(i) - ord('a') + 1 for i in p)))].append(p)

print d['111']
#[['a', 'k'], ['k', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]

print d['126']
#[['a', 'z'], ['l', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'f']]
```

Comment: I'm looking more for a solution of looping throughout all combination. If you see my example, I get "aa" and "ja". If give a input of d="111", I get "aaa", "ka" and "ak".

Comment: this code will do just that, just make d = defaultdict(list), and append each solution to d in the loop, as i mentioned

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it.

Comment: I completed the code for you, hope you like this style of code.